# CSS Transition not easing out

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

There are a lot of questions about this on SO, but none of them could help me.

I'm trying to ease in and out a background image based on button hover.
[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltv58jmh/1/)

```
HTML:
<div class="bg bg-home"></div>
<div class="main-menu" id="home">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>

JS:
$('#home').hover(function() {
    $('.bg.bg-home').addClass('home-main-menu');
},function() {
    $('.bg.bg-home').removeClass('home-main-menu');
});

CSS:
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
.bg {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0;
}
.bg-home {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index: -1; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.home-main-menu {
  background: url("http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2013/1/11/1357921737290/Masterclass-in-HTML5-and--006.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The problem is that the background image eases in fine, but does not ease out. I have also tried to only do the transition in opacity, but with the same result.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the background image to .bg-home itself. Then, the class which is added on hover will only need to affect the opacity and you'll have a smooth ease-out.

See this fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/Ltv58jmh/2/

```
.bg-home {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index: -1; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2013/1/11/1357921737290/Masterclass-in-HTML5-and--006.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    opacity:0;
}
.home-main-menu {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I think I over simplified the problem, but the answer to the question is correct and it lead me to solving my problem.